# How to globally set form formatter for doctrine generated forms?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I need to add asterisk after labels of fields, so I created my sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatterMy class.

I set this formatter in configure method:

```
$this->widgetSchema->setFormFormatterName('My');
$formatter = $this->widgetSchema->getFormFormatter();
if (!is_null($formatter))
  $formatter->setValidatorSchema($this->getValidatorSchema());
```

But it seem that I must repeat this for every generated form, every time that I use code generator of my modules.

Is this possible to set my formatter in settings.yml or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in your project configuration (`apps\<yourapp>\config\<yourapp>Configuration.php`).

```
class frontendConfiguration extends fwApplicationConfiguration {

    public function configure() {
        // ..Other code

        sfWidgetFormSchema::setDefaultFormFormatterName('YourFormatterName');
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to pass validator schema to current form: $formatter->setValidatorSchema($this->getValidatorSchema()); ? :/

Comment: mistake in comment above, not current form but from current to form to formatter.

Comment: Anywat I try to use event for this.